# Sonata create two entities but doesn't associate them

Tags: php, forms, symfony

In sonata admin I'm building products form which renders features form. Relations in my db are:

> ProductFeatures:FeaturesValues 1:n
>
> Product:FeaturesValues 1:n

```
class ProductAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
       $formMapper
         ->add('name')
         ->add('featureValues','collection', array(
                    'mapped' => true,
                    'type' => new \Bundle\Form\FeatureValueType(),
                    'allow_add' => true,
                ));
    }
}
```

FeatureValueType:

```
class FeatureValueType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('productFeature') 
            ->add('value')
        ;
    }
```

Feature value form renders features so automatically new feature value is associated with feature. The problem is when I try to do this in product form **after submitting it I get new Product, I get new feature value associated with feature, but Product is not associated with feature value** ( product_id in product_feature_value table is empty ).

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you set cascade-persist and linked your entities so that when they are created and linked PHP wise that is reflected DB wise?

Comment: I set cascade-persist, but how I'm supossed to link those entities? You mean in annotations like "ManyToOne" ? If that - I also have done this.

Comment: Something like : public function addEducation ($education)
    {
        $education->setUser($this);
        $this->educations[] = $education;
        return $this;
    } THEN you just update the object that has this class

Comment: but how am I supossed to get this $education object? In pre-persist action I can't from what I see.

Comment: I will write you a full answer when I am home.

Comment: I found out one solution but I hate it. This is in prePersist function:

 foreach($product->getFeatureValues() as $fv) {
            $fv->setProduct($ship);
        }

but it's nonsense...

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you have something like this with your classes.

```
// ...
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Product
{
  // ...

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FeatureValue", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist"})
   */
  protected $featureValues;

  public function __construct() {
      $this->featureValues = new ArrayCollection();
  }
  // ...
  /**
   * Add products
   *
   * @param Path\To\Entity\FeatureValue $featureValues
   * @return Product
   */
   public function addFeatureValue(\Path\To\Entity\FeatureValues $feauteValues)
   {
      $featureValues->setProduct($this);
      $this->featureValues[] = $featureValues;

      return $this;
   }
}

class FeatureValue
{
  // ...

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="featureValues")
   */
  protected $product;
}
```

This way  you only update the `Product` class by just adding new `FeatureValue`. It will automatically connect this two items because of the way method `addFeatureValue()` works, and if you have a new `FeatureValue` item added to the `Product` item you are updating, it will automatically persist in to the database, because you said so in the relationship rules.

Comment: yeah, I've done simillar thing in prePersist method and it works there, unfortunately Your way doesn't work..

Comment: from what I've noticed after submitting form method "addFeatureValue()" in Product is not even called.

Comment: I guess you should ask about this @Sonata's team about this